# How do I sort custom taxonomy using an ACF number field?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a site right now that requires a list of contacts broken up into departments. I've created a custom post type (`team_members`) with custom taxonomy (`team_category`), which contains multiple categories (Billing, Marketing, etc). These categories need to be sorted on a page with a list of the people in the categories below them in a grid. I have so far been able to display the categories and the people within them, however I'm so far unable to sort the categories themselves.

To sort the categories, I've created an ACF number field called `team_category_sort_order`, and each of the categories has a number from 1-9 assigned to it. I've been looking through every post and document I can find, but can't seem to find a solution that will allow me to use this number to adjust the display positions on the page.

My current code is pasted at the following URL:

https://pastebin.com/Lr8Sr2c5

I appreciate any and all help in understanding what I'm missing here. I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar in the past, although I haven't added in the posts for multiple tax categories on the same page.

Here is a solution you could try. I have used this method and it has worked for me to order cats the way I want using the number field, although as I mentioned my use case wasn't 100% exactly like yours but very similar.

**For your initial args for taxonomy cats:**

Two params I removed below. If you're setting a numeric value to order, you probably don't need to specify ASC or DESC most times, you just set the order using the numbers, unless I'm misunderstanding. Also meta compare shouldn't be necessary either. Should be as simple as just querying the terms and ordering them by meta key.

```
$args = 
   array(
     'taxonomy'     => 'team_category',
     'orderby'      => 'meta_value', // change this to just use meta_value vs. meta_value_num
     'meta_key'     => 'team_category_sort_order'
   );

$_terms = get_terms( $args ); // Get your terms
```